# Trying to use NodeMCU ESP-12e, a 5v relay AND a solenoid lock on same 12v power wall-wart

Tags: esp8266, power, nodemcu, relay

Noob here, so be gentle.

Using a 12v-5/3.3v power board, NodeMCU powers relay fine, 100% of the time. Add in the solenoid by soldering a line from the wall wart into the COM spot on the relay, and then 10-15% of the time, the activation of the solenoid resets the NodeMCU. Common ground for all of them obviously.

It should be possible to run them all, yes? But what do I need to add into the chain to keep the reset from happening? A capacitor? Magic? Help.

Comment: Can you edit your question to draw a circuit diagram using the schematic tool?

Comment: do you have a flyback diode on your coils? if not, get ASAP. a cap might help if undervoltage is what resets the MCU

Comment: What is your power board?